# How to skip execution of " Scenario Outline"

Tags: cucumber, cypress, gherkin

I have n number of *Scenarios* in a feature file with a *Scenario Outline* und a "Background" Block to run a predefined set of steps before each Scenario.
Using Tag "@focus" to run a specific Scenario and "@Force Pending" to skip the rest, but when the Feature file is executed in the runner, the execution steps through the *Scenario Outline* also(Of course at the end, in the statistics, it would be counted as skipped Test).
Unfortunately, this consumes lots of time. Is there a way i could optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Most Cucumber flavours support a sytax for the feature path like this:

```
path/to/example.feature:16:32
```

Here 16 and 32 are line numbers for examples or scenarios. So you can pick which scenarios or examples to run without adding tags.

How to provide the feature path depends on your Cucumber flavour. Check the docs.

And if it doesn't work, you may want to create a bug report.